# How can I determine what is emitting chemical fumes in my home?

Tags: insulation, attic, smell

Our home is a reconstructed 1890's log home moved and rebuilt in the late 70's or early 80's. They used 1 inch thick styrofoam board in the ceiling under the pine tongue and groove. I think it is the foam board that is off gassing. There is no plastic vapor barrier. How can I narrow down the odor. Is there any information about off gassing of the light weight insulation - It looks like  tiny Styrofoam balls pressed lightly together to make the boards.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge 38+ year old foam should be long done off gassing it's manufacturing odors.    Most likely some other source of off gassing...any recent  furniture purchases?

Comment: Yeah, that type of foam board doesn't have much of an odor to begin with. It's long gone by now. You haven't told us anything about the nature of the odor. Have you considered pet or pest urine?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if it’s the styrofoam you’re smelling. It’s probably the chinking, especially if you’ve reinstalled or touched up lately.

All of the chinking manufacturers caution against touching, rubbing, etc. because of skin irritations and caution about inhalation.

Comment: styrofoarm could absorb moisture which inturn could absorb other orders or rotten insects etc.